# Tensorflow python classification training with subcategories

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

The problem im facing is that i need to train a tensorflow graph with "maincategories" and "subcategories".

I already know how to fully train a graph with "maincategories".

For example i have 3 different animal types: cat, dog and elephant.

If i train a graph with pictures to those 3 types, it would return scores for the 3 types like:

cat 0,7

dog 0,3

elephant 0,02

What i want tho is to train those 3 types and subcategories for those types, for example:

cat: white, fat, ...

dog: husky, ...

And when i now classify an image with this graph, i would like to get an output with the maincategories and the subcategories, like this:

cat: 0,7 -> white:0,3 -> fat:0,5

dog: 0,2 .....

currently the only way i see is to train a graph with the maincategories and to train individual graphs for all the maincategories with the subcategories, then code something like:

```
if name=='cat' and score>=0,7:
  classify again with catgraph and get results
```

In the example the catgraph would be a trained with the different cattypes as categories.

This however isnt very ellegant and im hoping there is better way of doing this.

Im thankfull for any help you could give me.

~Meow

Answer (score 0):

You can train a graph with two outputs, sharing everything but the last layer (or up to a layer you like). Then you would have a (say) logloss for each, and optimize against the sum of the losses. If you are bottlenecked by the learning capacity of the network, you may want to weigh one loss more than the other.

Remember to track both losses in the summary for easy visualization. You can add the losses to the losses collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to train the subcategories individually. Point the `--image_dir` to the root of your subcategories. NOTE: the subcategories here am refering to are the subfolders. Then get the output of each subcategory as you would with the main category. I hope this sheds some light. You can refer to [Tensorflow image retraining](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)